# How much work can be done on a liquid through compression?

Tags: thermodynamics, liquid-state

Work can be done on a gas by compressing it in an adiabatic process, raising its temperature. I'm wondering if the same thing could be done on a liquid, since liquids aren't truly incompressible. If work can be done on a liquid this way, does it raise the temperature of the liquid, and is there an asymptotic limit to how much work could be done on the liquid as pressure steadily increases?

Comment: You are dealing with PV work, where the change in volume is VERY small.

Answer (score 2):

The general expression for the temperature increase upon pressurization is $\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)_S$, where $T$ is temperature, $P$ is pressure, and $S$ is entropy, which we hold constant to represent the lack of heat loss to the surrounding environment. (In practice, we achieve this by performing the compression fairly rapidly or by insulating the system.)

Applying the [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule) and a [Maxwell relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations), we have

$$\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)_S=-\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\right)_P\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_T=\frac{T}{C_P}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P=\frac{V\alpha T}{C_P},$$

where $\alpha$ is the volumetric thermal expansion coefficient and $C_P$ is the constant-pressure heat capacity. Thus, **materials that expand (contract) when heated tend to heat up (cool down) when pressurized.** This applies to all materials, including liquids.

(For an ideal gas, $\alpha=1/T$, giving us $dT/T=(nR/PC_P)dP$, which we integrate to obtain the [familiar isentropic expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isentropic_process) $TP^{(\gamma-1)/\gamma}=\mathrm{constant}$, where $\gamma$ is the heat capacity ratio.)

We can increase the compression to be arbitrarily high (astrophysicists can weigh in on whether black hole formation would follow). Expect the bulk modulus to skyrocket and a phase transition to the solid state (which offers denser atomic packing) to ultimately occur.

Comment: Sorry I meant is there a limit to the work that can be done (aka how much the temperature can be raised), not a limit to the pressure.

Comment: I'm not aware of a temperature limit associated with this effect in particular.

Comment: In addition to the equation that @Chemomechanics gave you, there is also the equation for V as a function of P and T:  $$V=V(P_0,T_0)\exp{\left(\alpha(T-T_0)-\frac{(P-P_0)}{B}\right)}$$where B is the bulk modulus.  These two relationships give you what you need to determine the integral PdV at constant S.

Answer (score 0):

Linearizing the equation of state, we have $$dV=V_0\left[\alpha dT-\frac{dP}{B}\right]$$where B is the bulk modulus.  And, from @chemometrics equation, we have $$dT=\frac{V_0\alpha T_0}{C_p}dP$$So, combining these two equations, we have $$dV=-V_0\left(\frac{1}{B}-\frac{V_0\alpha^2 T_0}{C_p}\right)dP$$and $$dW=PdV=-V_0\left(\frac{1}{B}-\frac{V_0\alpha^2 T_0}{C_p}\right)PdP$$